# How to return a default parameter while calling object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I am using routes variable to return routes to various urls.

```
export const routes = {
    root: {  path: '/' },
    login: { path: '/login' },
    users: { path: '/users'}
}
```

Now, I have to use it like routes.login.path now. But is there any way that if nothing is passed after the parameter, it takes 'path' by default. Something like this: routes.login should automatically return '/login'

Comment: what router are you using?

Comment: Why do you need the `path` sub-property  then? Without understanding that, I would just suggest you use `const routes = {login: "/login", ...}`

Comment: @JuanMendes Because, in future, to add another property just in case if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You want `routes.login` to return the string `"/login"`, and you want to access `.path` through that string. I would recommend you to rethink the the way you are approaching this problem.

Nevertheless, there are two ways to achieve this:

One is to assign a `path` property onto each string like so:

```js
export const routes = {
    root: Object.assign('/', {  get path() {return String(this)} }),
    login: Object.assign('/login', {  get path() {return String(this)} }),,
    users: Object.assign('/users', {  get path() {return String(this)} }),
}
```

The other is to override the `toString` method of the object:

```js
export const routes = {
    root: {  path: '/', toString() {return this.path} },
    login: { path: '/login', toString() {return this.path} },
    users: { path: '/users', toString() {return this.path} }
}
```

---

Of course, you can clean this up with a separate class:

```js
// First Method
class Route extends String {
  get path() { return String(this) }
}

export const routes = {
    root: new Route('/'),
    login: new Route('/login'),
    users: new Route('/users')
}

// Second Method
class Route {
  constructor(data) {
    Object.assign(this, data);
  }
  toString() {
    return this.path;
  }
}

export const routes = {
    root: new Route({  path: '/' }),
    login: new Route({ path: '/login' }),
    users: new Route({ path: '/users' })
}
```

Comment: I almost wrote an answer just like your option with a separate class! The first approach seems kind of weird but I guess it works. It may, however, clash if there are routes with the same names as string methods.

Comment: Yeah, its a bit hacky - wouldn't actually recommend doing something like this but its the closest to what OP asked. Since they didn't want to add `.path` I wasn't sure if they were going to cast to string or not, so I just posted both solutions.